# How to properly handle 3D data and create heatmaps in gnuplot 4.6?

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I have temperature data from eight different nonequidistant depths over several days and I would like to plot it as heatmap. As far as I know I have two options. I can use "with image" but that assumes equidistant points so that makes just 8 pixel thin strip or I can use pm3d which need proper grid(I am not sure what proper grid is). I found that dgrid3d can make the grid for me but that erases any dependency on depth for some reason. Can someone please explain this behavior to me?
Here is the code and the data I use.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2TfUgjtGRVReV9ocFVvM1BKd2M

```
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set xdata time

set view map
set dgrid3d

splot './Data/MO-03t_.txt' every ::2 u 1:3:4 with pm3d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `dgrid3d` does not plot *your* data. Instead, something like two-dimensional splines are calculated from your data. Then, gnuplot creates a (by default) 10x10 matrix, and fills it with values interpolated from the splines. This matrix is then plotted.

But I have an other solution for you:

```
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set xdata time

# for the nice colors
set pm3d

# For debugging: place ticmarks only vor values with data 
set ytics (0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.11, 0.31, 0.41, 0.61, 0.91)

plot  './Data/MO-03t_.txt' every ::2 u 1:3:(1800):($3<0.2?.005:0.05):4  w boxxyerrorbars fs solid lc palette
```

The `boxxerrorbars ... lc palette` takes `using <x>:<y>:<deltaX><deltaX>:<z>`

The delta values are half the width of the boxes, i.e. it means plot a box from x-deltaX;y-deltaY to x+deltaX;y+deltaY for each datapoint.

Here, the width of the boxes is 3600 seconds, the height is either 0.1 or 0.01, depending on the y-value.

Here is the result:

[image]

However, you can still improve the height of the boxes.

And instead of 4+1 columns, you can also pass 6+1 columns with

`using <x>:<y>:<xlow>:<ylow>:<xhigh>:<yhigh>:<z>`

Here, the borders of the boxes are given as absolute values, not as distance from the x-y-value.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably better solution than messing with splines.